# How do I get contents of span class (console.log)

Tags: javascript

I have a page that is structured like below and I would like to extract 'TEXT' from span class "spanName".

I've tried to use `getElementbyClassName`, `getElementbyId` with no luck.

```html
<section id="level1" class="level1a">
  <div class>
    <div class="level3">
      <div class="level4">
        <span class="spanName">TEXT</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: Please include the JavaScript that you actually tried in the snippet. `getElementbyClassName` and `getElementbyId` aren’t existing functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)** returns a **[NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NodeList)** collection of elements. All you need to do is access the index of the NodeList collection in combination with **[`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)**:

```js
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('spanName')[0].innerHTML);
```

```html
<section id="level1" class="level1a">
  <div class>
    <div class="level3">
      <div class="level4">
        <span class="spanName">TEXT</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Alternatively, you can grab the element based on the ID `level1` and traverse down with **[`childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes)**:

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('level1').childNodes[1].childNodes[1].childNodes[1].childNodes[1].innerHTML);
```

```html
<section id="level1" class="level1a">
  <div class>
    <div class="level3">
      <div class="level4">
        <span class="spanName">TEXT</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Or make use of **[`getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName)** to look for `<span>`:

```js
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML);
```

```html
<section id="level1" class="level1a">
  <div class>
    <div class="level3">
      <div class="level4">
        <span class="spanName">TEXT</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Then your element either does not have the class you expect it to, or you're accessing it via the wrong index due to additional content also falling into the selection criteria. As you can see in my above example(s), the selector definitely targets the desired element -- you may need to include more context if it does not work for you.

Comment: Thanks - Your link gave me the structure to the answer so marking this as the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

```
document.getElementById('level1').getElementsByClassName('spanName')[0].innerText
```

Comment: Better still use [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) or [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). `document.querySelectorAll('#level .spanName')[0].innerText`

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in different ways, here is an example which may help you:

```js
var span = document.querySelector('.spanName');

console.log(span.innerText);
```

```html
<section id="level1" class="level1a">
  <div class>
    <div class="level3">
      <div class="level4">
        <span class="spanName">TEXT</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```